# The group $G/H$ is isomorphic to one of $Z_8$, $Z_4\oplus Z_2$, or $Z_2\oplus Z_2\oplus Z_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning normal and factor groups. I am currently using the textbook Contemporary Abstract Algebra, 8th Edition, by Joseph A. Gallian. I stumbled upon an exercise question (Chapter 9, Exercise 25), which reads:

> Let $G=\left( \mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z} \right)^{\times}$ and $H =\{1, 31\}$. The group $G/H$ is isomorphic to one of $Z_8$, $Z_4\oplus Z_2$, or $Z_2\oplus Z_2\oplus Z_2$. Determine which one by elimination.

Do I have to find all possible cosets of the subgroup in order to determine which one is isomorphic to $G/H$, or do I just simply select an element in $U(32)$?

Comment: One easy way to eliminate possibilities is to look at the number of elements of some order. In this case, you want to look at elements of order 2, 4, and 8.

Comment: What is $U(32)$?

Comment: @angryavian U(32) is the group of numbers relatively prime to 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, the quotient is isomorphic to one of $\mathbb Z_8$, $\mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$, $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2$.

Take the element $3$ and find its order in $G/H$:
\begin{align}
3^1 \equiv 3\quad (\text{mod }32)\\
3^2 \equiv 9\quad (\text{mod }32)\\
3^3 \equiv 27\quad (\text{mod }32)\\
3^4 \equiv 17\quad (\text{mod }32)
\end{align}
The order can be only $1,2,4,8$. Since $3^1$, $3^2$ and $3^4$ do not lies in $H$, then $3$ has order equal to $8$ in $G/H$. So the quotient $G/H$ is cyclic (it has order equal to $8$ and we find an element with order exactly $8$) and $G/H\cong \mathbb Z_8$.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The powers of $3H$ in $G/H$ are $\{3,29\}, \{9, 23\}, \{27, 5\}, \{17, 15\}, \{19, 13\}, \{25, 7\}, \{11, 21\}, \{1, 31\}$, so there is an element of order $8$ in $G/H$.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Thanks!